fontsize of axis heading is not increasing plotly
I am trying to increase the font size of Boundary [0,1] and solution profile in my code as below, but their font size is not increasing. Below is the plotly code I am using.
Tried everyhing. Need help.
    layout = go.Layout(
        title={'text': f'cbits={cbits}, f = {f:.2e}, d = {d}', 'x': 0.5,'y': 0.95, 'xanchor': 'center', 'yanchor': 'top', 'font': {'size': 24}},
        xaxis=dict(title='Boundary [0,1]',
                   showgrid= True,
                   gridcolor= 'lightgrey',
                   titlefont= {'size': 24},
                   tickfont ={'size': 24}                  
                  ),    
        yaxis=dict(title='Solution Profile',
                   showgrid= True,
                   gridcolor='lightgrey',
                   titlefont={'size': 24},
                   tickfont = {'size': 24}
                  ), 
        width=650,
        height=500,
        margin=dict(l=50, r=50, b=50, t=50),
        legend = dict(
            font = dict(size=24),  
            orientation ="h",  
            x =0.5,   
            y = -0.1 , 
            xanchor = "center",  
            yanchor ="top"   
        ),

        plot_bgcolor = 'white',  # rgb(220, 255, 220)',  

        shapes=[
    # Add a rectangular border around the plot
            {
                'type': 'rect',
                'xref': 'paper',
                'yref': 'paper',
                'x0': 0,  # left side of the rectangle
                'y0': 0,  # bottom side of the rectangle
                'x1': 1,  # right side of the rectangle
                'y1': 1,  # top side of the rectangle
                'line': {
                    'color': 'darkgray',
                    'width': 1,
                },
                'fillcolor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',  # transparent fill
            }
        ]

    )


I have tried your code with the appropriate data. Correct, the axis title string is larger. Is your Plotly up to date?

Thank you @r-beginners for the help.  Thank you for helping in figuring out the problem.You are right. The code is correct. The problem was my carelessness. It was due to wrong paths.
